# Implementing the comparable interface

Tags: java, compare, comparable

I just found this exam question and cannot figure it out :

The following depicts a contrived partial class which implements the Comparable interface. The only purpose of this contrived class is comparing its instances with a given string.

There are two things we need to fill in in the class to finish it. Here is the class :

```
public class PrivateComparableClass // FILL IN PART 1 { 
   private String thing;

    public PrivateComparableClass(String thing) {
     this.thing=thing;
    }
   //FILL IN PART 2
}
```

I am assuming part 1 simply corresponds to :

```
public class PrivateComparableClass implements Comparable {
```

And part 2, I assume he is expecting an implementation of the compareTo method, but I don't really know how to properly go about implementing this:

```
public static int compareTo() {
  if this.thing.equals(thing){
  return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, part 1 should really be:

```
public class PrivateComparableClass implements Comparable<PrivateComparableClass> {
```

As to part 2, if `thing` is the only data member in the class, you can simply piggyback on `String.compareTo`:

```
public int compareTo(PrivateComparableClass rhs) {
  return this.thing.compareTo(rhs.thing);
}
```

I recommend that you read up on how [`compareTo` is meant to work](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) (there are three possible outcomes: less than, equal to and greater than).

Comment: I think it shouldn't be `static` :)

Comment: @Messa: Good catch, thanks! Copy-and-paste error on my part. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit:

Comparator functions typically take two arguments (let's call them A and B) and follow the convention of returning

- -1 if A < B
- 0 if A == B
- 1 if A > B

Also, compareTo should not be declared 'static' if you are using an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

First, the `Comparable` interface is generic; your declarations should specify a type parameter:

```
public class PrivateComparableClass 
  implements Comparable<PrivateComparableClass> {
```

Then, you should compare the `thing` members of the class in a `compareTo()` method (which is an instance method, not a class member).

```
@Override
public final int compareTo(PrivateComparableClass that) {
  return this.thing.compareTo(that.thing);
}
```

A well-behaved `Comparable` should implement an `equals()` method that is consistent with its `compareTo()` method:

```
@Override
public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == this)
    return true;
  if (!(obj instanceof PrivateComparableClass))
    return false;
  return compareTo((PrivateComparableClass) obj) == 0;
}
```

And, when you override `equals()`, you need to override `hashCode()` too:

```
@Override
public final int hashCode() {
  return thing.hashCode();
}
```

If `thing` is truly allowed to be `null`, suitable null-checking behavior should be added to each method.

Comment: In your equals override your last line should be: return compareTo((PrivateComparableClass) obj) == 0;

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is more or less how the class should be declared and implemented

```
public class PrivateComparableClass implements Comparable<PrivateComparableClass>
{
    private String thing;
    //... other stuff

    public int compareTo(PrivateComparableClass o)
    {
       return this.thing.compareTo(o.thing);
    }
}
```